# Objective C - Send Object with Multipeer Connectivity Framework, Peer not connected

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity, peer

I'm developing an application and I need to send an object to another application. These two apps communicate each other using the multipeer connectivity framework.

In particular, I want to send an object called Order, that is

```
@interface Order : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *customerName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *arrivalTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *totalPrice;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *products;

@end
```

from a "client" application called OrderAndPay to a "server" app called POS. Here is how I send this object in my OrderAndPay app delegate

```
NSData *dataToBeSent = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.order];
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self.mpHandler.session connectedPeers], nil];

if ([self.mpHandler.session sendData:dataToBeSent
                            toPeers: array
                           withMode:MCSessionSendDataUnreliable
                              error:&error]) {
    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

But I always got NO as a result!!! When I try to debug, xCode say

> Printing description of error: Error Domain=MCSession Code=1 "Peers (
>           (
>           POS
>       ) ) not connected" UserInfo=0x16e8bcb0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Peers (
>           (
>           POS
>       ) ) not connected}

So it seems that POS is not connected. But as I wrote before, I get my peers using the method `connectedPeers` of my `MCSession`!!!

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I've changed the call in the if statement in

```
[self.mpHandler.session sendData:dataToBeSent
                            toPeers: [self.mpHandler.session connectedPeers]
                           withMode:MCSessionSendDataUnreliable
                              error:&error]
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give same sessionType in both applications..
`static NSString * const kMCSessionServiceType = @"mcsessionp2p";`

```
 _serviceAdvertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:self.peerID
                                                       discoveryInfo:nil
                                                         serviceType:kMCSessionServiceType];


// Create the service browser
_serviceBrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:self.peerID
                                                   serviceType:kMCSessionServiceType
```